# How do I change image view size in cell?

Tags: swift

I have managed to change the row height for my cell, but now the image I use as an icon remains the same size and now is too small. I want it to be 72x72 stuck to the left-hand side of the cell.

I am using the following in `cellForRowAtIndexPath`:

```
override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

    let cell = cellForTableView(tableView)
    let checklist = dataModel.lists[indexPath.row]
    cell.textLabel?.textColor = UIColor(red: 25.0/255.0, green: 25.0/255.0, blue: 112.0/255.0, alpha: 1.0)
    cell.textLabel?.font = font
    cell.textLabel!.text = checklist.name
    cell.textLabel?.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth = true
    cell.textLabel?.textAlignment = NSTextAlignment.Left
    cell.accessoryType = .DetailDisclosureButton
    cell.backgroundColor = UIColor.whiteColor().colorWithAlphaComponent(0.5)

    cell.imageView!.image = UIImage(named: checklist.iconName)

    return cell
}

func cellForTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> UITableViewCell {
    let cellIdentifier = "Cell"
    if let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier(cellIdentifier) {
        return cell
    } else {
        return UITableViewCell(style: .Subtitle, reuseIdentifier: cellIdentifier)
    }
}
```

How do I set the size in that case?

Comment: Can you post some code how are creating the cell and imageView and are you using autolayout or framing.

Comment: Yep - just edited my question ;).

Comment: What about cell class? How are cells created?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you using storyboards? If so, you can use auto-layout and enforce width and height for the imageView. You can also attach it to the left side via autolayout.

There's also a nice cocoa pod that allows you to programmatically enforce autolayout constraints, called [SnapKit](https://github.com/SnapKit/SnapKit).

Comment: No, it is all done programmatically for that table view. Snapkit? I am giving it a look.

Comment: yeap, makes your life much easier.